# Wordpress Loop – Show an overlay with embedded video on click

Tags: wordpress, loops

i am currently working on my wordpress theme for http://archive.timrodenbroeker.de and i want my wp-loop to do the following:

• Ask: Is the (advanced) custom field „videoembed“ filled? 
(I use the advanced Custom field plugin“)
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

• If yes, create the linked text „button“

• If „button“ is clicked, switch the „overlay“-div’s display-value from „none“ to „block“ and insert the videoembed-code via AJAX, which is placed in the custom-field  „videoembed“

Well, that’s it, but I don’t know, how to code that. I need some help. Could you take a look on this? Would be amazing! Thank you guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started in the PHP, assuming the content in the `videoembed` field is a link to the video on Youtube or Vimeo:

```
$videoembed = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'videoembed');
if( !empty($videoembed) ) {
    echo '<a href="'.$videoembed.'" class="lightbox">Click me</a>';
}
```

To pop-up the lightbox you should use Javascript. The easiest way is to use a plugin for this part, like [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) or [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/)

Good luck!